# Unexpected runtime error (segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, new-operator, binaryfiles, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I am currently optimizing a memory intensive application to occupy lesser memory. What I am trying to do in the following code is to allocate the file stream objects `ifstream` and `ofstream` dynamically in order to free them exactly after it's use is no longer needed. The code functions perfectly for allocation/de-allocation of `ofstream` but crashes at runtime due to a possible segmentation fault when the memory contents of `ifstream` is de-allocated. The following is a snippet of the original code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Dummy class to emulate the issue at hand
class dummy {
    private:
    int randINT;
    static bool isSeeded; 
    public:
    dummy() { randINT=rand(); }
    int getVal() { return randINT; }
};
bool dummy::isSeeded=false;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    // Binary file I/O starts here
    dummy * obj;
    ofstream * outputFile;
    ifstream * inputFile;
    outputFile=new ofstream("bFile.bin",ios::binary);
    if (!(*outputFile).fail()) {
        obj=new dummy;
        cout << "Value to be stored: " << (*obj).getVal() << "\n";
        (*outputFile).write((char *) obj, sizeof(*obj)); // Save object to file
        (*outputFile).close();
        delete obj;
        // don't assign NULL to obj; obj MUST retain the address of the previous object it pointed to
    } else {
        cout << "Error in opening bFile.bin for writing data.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    delete outputFile; // This line throws no errors!
    inputFile=new ifstream("bFile.bin",ios::binary);
    if (!(*inputFile).fail()) {
        (*inputFile).read((char *) obj,sizeof(dummy)); // Read the object of type 'dummy' from the binary file and allocate the object at the address pointed by 'obj' i.e. the address of the previously de-allocated object of type 'dummy' 
        cout << "Stored Value: " << (*obj).getVal() << "\n";
        (*inputFile).close();
    } else {
        cout << "Error in opening bFile.bin for reading data.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    delete inputFile; // Runtime error is thrown here for no reason!

    cout << "\n-----END OF PROGRAM-----\n";

}
```

The above code saves an object to a binary file when the user evokes save functions. As stated in the code above, the de-allocation of `inputFile` pointer throws a runtime error.

Please note that I am using clang(more specifically, clang++) to compile the project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you come from a Java or C# background? Because in C++ you don't have to use `new` to create instance of objects. And that leads to less pointers, and less pointers are a good thing because using pointers wrongly is the most common reason for crashes.

Comment: `outputFile = new ofstream("bFile.bin",ios::binary);` is a very bad idea... Are you deliberately trying to defeat [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)?

Comment: The thing which stands out for me is the usage of `obj`  You're deleting the memory it points to, but keeping that address and attempting to reuse it... That's where I would start with this.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen I already considered those points to the best I could before posting the question!

Comment: @Some programmer dude I am fully aware of the fact that new is not needed to create objects in c++; I am using new and pointers to de-allocate/remove unnecessary objects from memory whenever required instead of waiting till the end of a method/function or program.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Like I mentioned earlier, I am doing that for dynamic allocation.

Comment: Also if you must use pointers, use `x->y` instead of `(*x).y`. Makes it much easier to read.

Comment: @LiamT I don't think there is a problem with that. The pointer 'obj' points to the memory location where object of type 'dummy' is stored. Had this been the root of the problem, a segmentation fault would be created when '(*inputFile).read((char *) obj,sizeof(dummy));' statement is evoked!

Comment: @Paul Rooney Does it? I'll make use of it in the future. Personally, I find the "*" one easier to read!

Comment: @hecate That is a premature micro-optimizations that is really unnecessary. And doesn't help much since the system will most likely keep the allocated pages mapped to your process anyway. It will also incur extra run-time overhead when it might not be needed. And defining variables in the innermost scope they are used will do what you're doing automatically. For example if you define `obj` inside the `if` check for the output file, it will do what you're doing now but in a nicer and more natural (and readable) way.

Comment: As for your problem, you read into `obj`, but by that time `obj` doesn't point to valid memory. Pointers are generally evil, don't use them unless you have to (mostly for polymorphism reasons). If you din't use pointers, you wouldn't have this *undefined behavior* and the crash.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your detailed explanation. I get it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::basic_istream::read(char_type*address, streamsize count)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) reads up to `count` characters and places them at `address`. It does **not** create any objects at `address`, as you seem to believe. The `address` must point to a valid chunk of memory at least `count*sizeof(char_type)` in size. By passing the address of a `delete`d object, you violate that condition: your code is broken and segmentation fault is **not unexpected**.

**EDIT**

What you're doing is [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), short UB. When you do that, nothing is guaranteed and any logic about what happens in which order invalid. The program is allowed to do anything, including immediately crashing, running for a while and then crashing, or ["make demons fly out of your nose"](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

In your case, I suspect that `std::basic_istream::read()` writing to unprotected memory causes some data to be overwritten, for example the address of another object, which later causes the segmentation fault. But this is pure speculation and not really worth pursuing.

In your case no object is created. The binary file just contains some bytes. The `read()` copies them to the address provided, which was not reserved for that purpose. To avoid the UB, simply add

```
obj = new dummy;
```

before the `read` to create an object.

If you want to re-use the memory from the previous object, you could use [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (see points 9 and 10 of that link). For example

```
char*buffer = nullptr;                  // pointer to potential memory buffer
if(writing) {
  if(!buffer)
    buffer = new char[sizeof(dummy)];   // reserve memory buffer
  auto pobj = new(buffer) dummy(args);  // create object in buffer
  write(buffer,sizeof(dummy));          // write bytes of object
  pobj->~pobj();                        // destruct object, but don't free buffer
}
if(reading) {
  if(!buffer)
    buffer = new char[sizeof(dummy)];   // not required if writing earlier
  read(buffer,sizeof(dummy));           // read bytes into object
  auto pobj = reinterpret_case<dummy*>(buffer); // no guarantees here
  use(pobj);                            // do something with the object read
  pobj->~pobj();                        // destruct object
}
delete[] buffer;                        // free reserved memory
```

Note that if the reading does not generate a valid object, the later usage of that object, i.e. the call to its destructor, may crash.

However, all this micro-optimisation is pointless anyway (it's only worth doing if you can avoid **many** calls to `new` and `delete`). Don't waste your time with that.

Comment: I still don't get it. If the problem was "passing the address of a deleted object", then the stored value would not be displayed as there would be an error when read () was called. And isn't the object ALREADY created when you read it from a binary file?

Comment: @hecate welcome to undefined behaviour!! [alternative version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/788ceb42e90b4904). You can use a scope to control when the object is deallocated, look up RAII.